# VPN activation warning message - Android

Tags: android, vpn

The linked imgae shows a meesage box that pops up when I try to configure the VPN programaically (using ToyVPN).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpc9df0k0w15nfw/screenshot.png

Is there any way to bypass this message without rooting my device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and even a rooted device is likely to say the same. This is Android's security framework kicking in. Because a VPN intercepts all network traffic, this potentially impacts all apps on your device, not just this one. Hence the need to explicitly gain approval from the user.